# switching between 2D and 3D with Picking

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, glut

So I'm trying to make a menu , and when I select an option I want it to draw the scene and to be able to pick from the scene in order to run the game. The game is checkers. I can do this without the 2D Menu, I perform the picking and the game is fine. But when I add the menu and try to switch between both, either I get no image (all black) or I set a perspective view and the Picking is no longer available in the same range.

to setup the 2D I make:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, 600, 600, 0, -1, 1); 
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
glLoadIdentity(); 
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glPushMatrix();
//draw 2D
```

to setup the 3D I use

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
glLoadIdentity(); 
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
glLoadIdentity(); 
gluPerspective(45.0, (GLdouble)600/(GLdouble)600, 1.0, 200.0); 
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
//draw 3D
```

With this I'm no longer able to pick objects from the scene, but I can pass from 2D to 3D and watch the entire scene.

To perform the picking:

```
void PickInterface::performPicking(int x, int y) { 

    glSelectBuffer (BUFSIZE, selectBuf);
    glRenderMode(GL_SELECT);
    glInitNames();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix ();
    GLfloat projmat[16];
    glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX,projmat);
    glLoadIdentity();
    GLint viewport[4];
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
    gluPickMatrix ((GLdouble) x, (GLdouble) (CGFapplication::height - y), 5.0, 5.0, viewport);
    glMultMatrixf(projmat);
    ((PickScene*)scene)->selectMode=true;
    scene->display();
    ((PickScene*)scene)->selectMode=false;
    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
    glPopMatrix ();

    glFlush();

    GLint hits;
    hits = glRenderMode(GL_RENDER);
    processHits(hits, selectBuf);
}
```

Comment: How do you perform the picking?

Comment: With te glClear, you are cleaning what you did before. You need to do the 3D rendering first... and the 2D render afterwards. After the 3D render, you shoudnt clean for the 2D render. Depending of how you are doing, it must be good to disable the DEPTH buffer.